# can not run first golang project in vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am new in golang.

i can not start my go file in VSCODE ,my code is simple

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("test")
}
```

when i run **go run main.go** in my terminal every thing works fine but when i save it in my vscode i get too many errors all like

*/work/src/golang.org/x/net/webdav/prop_test.go:217: encoding/xml.Name composite literal uses unkeyed fields*

my main.go file located at /work

how can i solve the problem ?

Comment: do you have any other source code files in the `webdav` package?

Comment: Turn of linting/veting/whatever of 3rd party packages in vscode.

Comment: And please get use to build your projects with `go build`. (Using `go run` is acceptable only for single file scripts and never for actual programs.)

Comment: @Volker where is veting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you've installed/unarchived Go at /work, which I assume is your home directory.

As a result, when you try and build your program which is also in /work (rather than use `go run` from the command line), all of the code underneath the /work directory where your main.go file are also being checked by VS Code.

The simplest solution might be to put your `main.go` file outside the `work` directory completely, or put it within the Go path at `/work/src/github.com/<your_username>/<your_package>`.

Comment: change  main.go directory , and put outside of /work solved my problem .